# Returning result of a list of functions using Return()

Tags: r, list, function, return

First, my English is not so correct, so I apologize in advance for any grammar mistakes/errors in my question.

I have this general function:

```
 .my_fun <- function(x,y,...){
      <body>
      return(
              list(
                    fun1 <- function(x){
                            <bodyfun1>
                         },
                    fun2 <- function(y){
                            <bodyfun2>
                         }, ....
                  )
            )
 }
```

to be used as auxiliary of:

```
 .my_funfun <- .my_fun(x,y,...)
```

and use ".my_funfun" as a code starter given the args of "my_fun"

I have to return values on the given order and of course return the result of the functions included on the body of the list. Normally, I would process the functions separately, store the results in separate objects and put the values of those objects in a list, and return that list (simplest way to do it), but I'm required to keep the structure I showed before.

My question is: is there any way to solve the functions in the body of the list and return those values, keeping the given structure? Or is it impossible to use return that way? I have used return() as a premature function stopper and as a fancy printer for objects in control structures, but this usage is new to me.

If you need the specific code elements I can provide them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Specific code elements with a working example and desired output will definitely help

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I already found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, doing stuff around, I realized what my mistake on the code was. The thing is that when i call

```
myfun$fun1
```

I got no answer. The right way to make the list is

```
.my_fun <- function(x,y,...){
    <body>
    return(
        list(
            fun1 = function(x){
                    <bodyfun1>
                     },
            fun2 = function(y){
                    <bodyfun2>
                     }, ....
              )
        )
 }
```

So i can use the name s"fun1, fun2 (...) as names to call in axiliary function.s

Example:I want to make a linear congruent random generator, with the following code:

```
.rCongLin <- function(a, c, m, x0){
    v1 <- x0
    return(
            list(seed=function(xw){
                            v1 <- xw},
                    nxt=function(){
                            v2 <- ((a*v1)+c)%%m
                            v3 <- v2/m
                            v1<<-v2
                            return(v3)
                    },
                    shw=function(){
                            return(list(a=a,c=c,m=m,x0=x0))}
            )
    )
}
```

The instruction:

```
.rCL <- .rCongLin(51864,35186,4153,1515)
```

starts the number generation given the function:

```
rCL=function(n){
        replicate(n,.rCL$nxt())}
rCL(45)
```

where `seed()` restarts x0, `nxt()` calculates the numbers and `shw()` shows the internal state (values for calculation). `rCL(n)` returns n number of replicas.

The thing is that `.rCL$x()` (where `x()` is any fun of those mentioned) returns NOTHING if you use '<-' operator (change it so u have a demonstration of what im talking about), but it does return with '='.

The answer is that the functions work with '=' because names are ASSIGNED on the lists with '=' (u name things in lists with '=') and not with '<-'. Therefore, in order to make the funtions... "citable" in the body of the `return(list(fun1, fun2...)` you need to assign the names `fun1, fun2...` using '='.

It was a simple answer. Got confused in using '=' and '<-' because in the original code every assignment is done with '='. Its prone to confuse novel programmers like me :(

Thanks a lot for your help!
Again Im sorry for any gramatical mistakes in this answer.
I hope this helps more people.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
my_fun <- function(x,y) {
    fun1 <- function(x) {
        length(x)
    }
    fun2 <- function(y) {
        sum(y)
    }
    list(fun1(x),fun2(y))
}
```